# I have some problems with file parsing

Tags: yii

I have some problems with file parsing, I'm new in Yii and I do not quite handle it, I have to select an xls file from the disk and parse it to display the data on it, I'm stuck here:

this is my view :

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\LinkPager;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>
<h1>Upload a file</h1>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'file')->fileInput() ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

<?php echo $model->file ?>
```

this is controller:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\data\Pagination;
use app\models\CatalogStudenti;
use app\models\UploadForm;
use Yii;


use yii\web\UploadedFile;
class SiteController extends Controller
{   


  public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model = new UploadForm();

        if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
            $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
            if ($model->upload()) {
                // file is uploaded successfully
                return;
            }
        }

        return $this->render('index', ['model' => $model]);
    }
}
```

and this is model:

```
<?php


namespace app\models;

use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

class UploadForm extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var UploadedFile
     */
    public $file;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['file'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 
     'xls, xlsx'],
        ];
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $this->file->saveAs('uploads/' . $this->file->baseName . '.' 
         . $this->file->extension);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to send data from view to controller for parse and then come back to view to display that data

Comment: you can use https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet after uploading the file

Comment: Thank you. I have the part who parse the file, but i don't know how to send selected file to my function who parse files, and after parse to render parsed data back to view for display it